# I need a command to remove all files from a directory (and subdir) that are under 20MB

Tags: command-line, automation

With the exception of certain file extensions.  (removing junk other than subtitle files from a video directory)

Answer (score 6):

First, run

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.sub' ! -name '*.srt' -size -20M -print
```

to check that it mathes only file types that you want. I'm a long time unix user and I always do this before asking any command to remove anything (typos always happen at the worst possible time). Then *edit* the previous command line to become

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.sub' ! -name '*.srt' -size -20M -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f
```

and run it. It should do what you want. You can repeat the `! -name '*.srt'` part more times if you need to exclude more files. Be careful to include the single quotes: they are important to prevent the shell from doing filename expansion.

Comment: I'd argue `-exec rm {} \;` or `-delete` is cleaner than piping through `xargs`

Comment: I'd argue that using `-delete` or `-exec rm '{}' \;` is more error prone than using `xargs -0`:  `-delete` is position dependent so you can inadvertently delete more than you intended and `-exec rm '{}' \;` doesn't specify how it treats unusual filenames.

Comment: @Oli: and `{}` needs to be quoted so to avoid expansion by the shell

Comment: `find` would be best stripped of any action other than `-print0`. It single-handedly breaks most all the Unix principles of "do one thing, do it well, interact with other programs". (Yeah, I know how many legacy scripts depend on `-exec`, so then I recommend that people *pretend* it doesn't exist)

Comment: @Li Lo: No, `{}` doesn't need quotation. Try it.

Comment: @msw: Because find does one thing well, it is to be preferred over other solutions, fiddling around with -print0, just to invoke other programs like xargs, to push the work further.

Answer (score 1):

here:

```
find . -type f -name *.bak -size -20M -exec rm {} \;
```

with `-name *.bak` you are looking for files with extension "bak", `-type f` is looking for files (not directories), `-size -20M` give you all files smaller than 20MB (`-size +20M` for the reverse search of files bigger than 20MB) and with the `-exec` you are removing the results of this search.

Comment: You should quote the pattern as well as {} to prevent the shell from expanding them.

Comment: No, you only need to quote the `"*.bak"`, not the {}. And instead of `-exec rm {} \;` you can just use `-delete`. And the question was **not** to delete files of some extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.ext' -size -20M -delete
```

is more easy to type and remember than anything else. You have to remember that -delete is position dependent, and deletes without further notice and trashcan.

Just be careful, backup often, and test before deleting:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.ext' -size -20M
```